# Method to calculate the best way to repay two different loans given a set amount of money per month?

Tags: optimization, finance

Given two (or more) loans of different balances and interest rates and a single amount of funds available per payment period, is there a way to calculate the best way to split the available funds to minimize the amount of money repaid?

I'm not really sure where to start to look into this type of question so if someone could point me in the right direction or provide an answer that would be great!

Comment: Repay as little of the lower interest rate loan as possible.

Comment: That won't always be optimal. It all depends on the details. If you have a card with a lower interest rate but a very small balance, it can benefit you to pay it off before the higher interest rate with a large balance.

Comment: You'd have to do the math on the details, obviously. But, if the the balances between the lower interest rate and higher interest rate is big enough, you can save money eliminating the lower interest rate balance first.

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of comparing interest rates. Whatever total payment you will make, use as little of it as allowed on the lower interest rate loan.